# opening .cc file in visual studio from within python module

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python for a software. I want to add a feature in my software to open .cc file and edit it. I am currently using Ubuntu so I know that I can use

```
Popen(['gedit', '/home/test/myfile.cc'], PIPE=stdout)
```

inside my python module to open this file. But If user is using my software on Window OS and wants to open .cc file in visual studio. Is there any way, we can open the .cc file in visual studio from within python module.

Comment: See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Are you looking for the command line for visual studio? Take a look to this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa991989(v=vs.80).aspx But it seems to require a running instance.